# Same GA ClientID for multiple users

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, clientid

We collect GA ClientIDs from the forms that are submitted on our websites and write them into hidden fields so we can use them in Google Analytics.

Lately, I have noticed that 55 users have exactly the same GA ClientID as each other and given that this number is a Browser/Device pair with the last 8 digits after the . being a timestamp, how on earth could this be happening?

My first thought was a Bot until I noticed that one of the test submissions was ME and it was using that same ID.

Any theories or thoughts would be much appreciated.